# How can I finding the Modify/Access/Change time of a file or directory?

Tags: command-line, timestamps

I am using Debian 7.2 and would like to know the shell command for finding the MAC time of a file or directory.  I tried

```
man -k "MAC"
```

and got a lot of hits about macros.  I then tried

```
man -k "MAC time"
```

and got nothing.

Comment: Is `stat yourfile` working?

Comment: What is a “MAC time”?

Comment: Modify, Access, Create time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By MAC I assume you're asking about Modify, Access, and Change timestamps. You can get these from the `stat` command.

#### Example

```
$ ls -l LICENSE 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 810 Jul  5  2012 LICENSE

$ stat LICENSE 
  File: `LICENSE'
  Size: 810         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 11409231    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2012-07-05 19:05:22.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2012-07-05 19:05:22.000000000 -0400
Change: 2013-10-16 21:17:31.148341667 -0400
```

#### Details

- Access: 2012-07-05 19:05:22.000000000 -0400 – Last access time of the file.
- Modify: 2012-07-05 19:05:22.000000000 -0400 – Last modification time of the file.
- Change: 2013-10-16 21:17:31.148341667 -0400 – Last change time of the inode data of that file.

Comment: Create timestamps? Not on most unices. C is for inode Change.